# Mount.cifs with krb5 fails while smbclient with same krb5-ticket works

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

We need to generate impersonated krb5-tickets (TGS) by using the S4U2Proxy extension. The tickets are built successfully and we can use them e.g. with smbclient without any problems. But in fact, we need to use them with mount.cifs or mount.nfs which is not working.

When doing kinit (what means having a TGT) mount works without any problems.

Does mount, or the underlying functions require having a TGT?
(Smbclient obviously does not).
And if not: Are there special requirements for a krb5-ticket used by mount?

Here's the error message:

```
mount error(126): Required key not available
```

I think this is the most important output of dmesg (see full output below):

```
cifs_spnego.c: key description = ver=0x2;host=file.mydomain.local;ip4=10.211.55.28;sec=krb5;uid=0x0;creduid=0x3e8;user=jdoe;pid=0x289a

CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -126
```

Ubuntu 18.04, kernel version 4.15.0-66-generic

klist:

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: jdoe@mydomain.local

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
11/10/19 06:23:34  11/10/19 16:23:34  cifs/file.mydomain.local@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
    renew until 11/11/19 06:23:34
```

mount command used:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=jdoe,domain=mydomain.local,sec=krb5,cruid=1000 //file.mydomain.local/share1 /mnt
```

Full dmesg output:

```
connect.c: Username: jdoe
connect.c: file mode: 0x1ed  dir mode: 0x1ed
connect.c: CIFS VFS: in cifs_mount as Xid: 182 with uid: 0
connect.c: UNC: \\file.mydomain.local\share1
connect.c: Socket created
connect.c: sndbuf 16384 rcvbuf 87380 rcvtimeo 0x6d6
fscache.c: cifs_fscache_get_client_cookie: (0x00000000dabd1b06/0x00000000d1987345)
connect.c: CIFS VFS: in cifs_get_smb_ses as Xid: 183 with uid: 0
connect.c: Existing smb sess not found
smb2pdu.c: Negotiate protocol
transport.c: Sending smb: smb_len=106
connect.c: Demultiplex PID: 10396
connect.c: RFC1002 header 0xf8
smb2misc.c: smb2_check_message length: 0xfc, smb_buf_length: 0xf8
smb2misc.c: SMB2 data length 120 offset 128
smb2misc.c: SMB2 len 252
transport.c: cifs_sync_mid_result: cmd=0 mid=0 state=4
misc.c: Null buffer passed to cifs_small_buf_release
smb2pdu.c: mode 0x1
smb2pdu.c: negotiated smb3.02 dialect
asn1.c: OID len = 10 oid = 0x1 0x3 0x6 0x1
asn1.c: OID len = 7 oid = 0x1 0x2 0x348 0xbb92
asn1.c: OID len = 7 oid = 0x1 0x2 0x348 0x1bb92
asn1.c: OID len = 8 oid = 0x1 0x2 0x348 0x1bb92
asn1.c: OID len = 10 oid = 0x1 0x3 0x6 0x1
connect.c: Security Mode: 0x1 Capabilities: 0x300067 TimeAdjust: 0
smb2pdu.c: Session Setup
smb2pdu.c: sess setup type 5
cifs_spnego.c: key description = ver=0x2;host=file.mydomain.local;ip4=10.211.55.28;sec=krb5;uid=0x0;creduid=0x3e8;user=jdoe;pid=0x289a
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -126
connect.c: CIFS VFS: leaving cifs_get_smb_ses (xid = 183) rc = -126
fscache.c: cifs_fscache_release_client_cookie: (0x00000000dabd1b06/0x00000000d1987345)
connect.c: CIFS VFS: leaving cifs_mount (xid = 182) rc = -126
```

Comment: Do you have keyutils installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, keyutils are installed. Meanwhile, we found out that "mount" needs a corresponding entry in the keytab file pointing to kerberos.

Comment: What do you mean "a corresponding entry in the keytab file"?