# Mount.cifs with krb5 fails on 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, mount, pam, active-directory

I have a Synology NAS and multiple Ubuntu Clients in my network. I setup Active Directory integration on the clients following the instructions here https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd.
Everything works splendid.
However, trying to setup a mount action on login following these instructions here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently fails.
I setup the mount using the instructions from chapter "Mount password protected shares using libpam_mount (Ubuntu 9.04)". I setup the .pam_mount.conf.xml file and added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pam_mount>
<volume options="uid=$USER,gid=100,dmask=0700" user="*" mountpoint="/mnt/shares/pictures" path="Pictures" server="serverIpAddress" >
</pam_mount>
```

Following the debugging strategy I tried to mount everything manually to see where it gets stuck. I can mount the share when using sudo and using default security type with user and password

```
sudo mount -t cifs -ousername=myname //myserver/Pictures /media/shares/test
```

When trying to use sec=krb5

```
sudo mount -t cifs -osec=krb5 //myserver/Pictures /media/shares/test
```

it returns the very helpful message **mount error(2): No such file or directory**. Dmesg is showing this

```
CIFS: VFS: Verify user has a krb5 ticket and keyutils is installed
CIFS: VFS: \\myserver Send error in SessSetup = -126
CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

Researching the web I spend hours trying to set the version, gid, uid, cruid in the mount command but nothing works. From what I can see I am also getting a correct kerberos ticket using klist. Some post suggested this check.

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_710201106_e2vIcu
Default principal: myName@ZIMMI.LOCALE

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
12.04.2021 08:52:57  12.04.2021 18:52:57  krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.LOCALE@MYDOMAIN.LOCALE
renew until 13.04.2021 08:52:57
```

I also checked with smbclient if I can see the shares from my NAS using the kerberos ticket and that works fine too.

```
smbclient -k -L myserver.mydomain.locale
```

There is a similar post bases on Ubuntu 18.04, I am using 20.04 LTS, here [Mount.cifs with krb5 fails while smbclient with same krb5-ticket works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187693/mount-cifs-with-krb5-fails-while-smbclient-with-same-krb5-ticket-works)

I checked that keyutils is installed but don't know how to implement that answer about te keytab file and I lack the knowledge to judge if that is actually the problem ("mount" needs a corresponding entry in the keytab file pointing to kerberos).

Thanks for any suggestion that might help to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I managed to get it to work. I don't know if the below setup is the only change that was needed. I was trying a lot of different things but at the end I managed to mount the share using pam when login into my domain account from terminal.

```
sudo login
```

This gave me the actual needed feedback that I needed. Apparently the options "nodev" and "nosuid" are needed.

My finally .pam_mount.conf.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<pam_mount>

<volume options="nodev,nosuid"
    fstype="cifs"
    server="servername.domainname"
    path="music"
    mountpoint="/home/user@domainname/shares/Music"
    cruid="user@domainname" />
</pam_mount>
```

where domain name is in syntax of name.locale

For those that don't know what the cruid is for (from mount manpage):
cruid=arg
sets the uid of the owner of the credentials cache. This is primarily useful with sec=krb5. The default is the real uid of the process performing the mount. Setting this parameter directs the upcall to look for a credentials cache owned by that user.

**Update on May 10th,** answering the question from SerG:
I can mount a share manually with this command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=$USER,domain=mydomain.locale,cruid=$USER,gid=xxx,uid=xxx,sec=krb5 //myserver/shareName/home /myUserName@mydomain.locale/shares/shareName
enter code here
```

For test purpose I added the actual gid and uid as the numeric value. you can get the two values when typing

```
id
```

It does't really matter where to mount it but I used a folder in my home directory to rule out additional permission issues.

Comment: So could you show a working command mount.cifs then?